# Why does SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF have to be registered in Java code?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

Posts of people trying to register a broadcast receiver in the manifest for events `SCREEN_ON` and `SCREEN_OFF` are numerous. The solution was given many times: register it in the java code.

My question is: WHY?

This makes no sense to me... And makes no sense to many others, as we can see:

- [Android broadcast receiver not working when trying to receive bootcomplete or screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770361/android-broadcast-receiver-not-working-when-trying-to-receive-bootcomplete-or-sc)
- [android: broadcast receiver for screen on and screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off)
- [Android - how to receive broadcast intents ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off)
- [Why my BroadcastReceiver doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467505/why-my-broadcastreceiver-doesnt-work)

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Various system broadcasts, particularly those related to power, have this restriction, so Android does not have to go fork a bunch of processes to handle all the requests for the broadcast from apps that are not presently running.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. It would be for performance. I guess the manifest intent filters are kept only on disk while the java registered ones are in memory. Is that correct?

Comment: The filters are always in memory AFAIK, but in a core OS process. What matters is the *app's* process, which always exists for `registerReceiver()` and may or may not exist for manifest-registered receivers. The pre-eminent example is `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, which has the same restriction. If Android had to go run a bunch of apps, forking processes for each, every time the battery drops a bit of charge, that's a lot of system churn. Worst-case? All that work causes the battery to drop another bit of charge, and you have to do all that work all over again, in a death spiral. :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I'm satisfied with this explanation.